# Issue with Compile

Tags: syntax, compile

The following code works fine with the the function `f` defined as a module, however, when I convert it to be a compiled function, it gives me errors. Can some one help me identify the problem is with the following code:

```
demand[n_, k_] := Min[k Vf, n capacity]; 
supply[n_, k_] := Min[(n Kj - k) w, n capacity]; 
flo[n_, ku_, kd_] := Min[demand[n, ku], supply[n, kd]];
gamma[ku_, kd_] := Min[1, supply[L, kd]/(demand[L, ku] + 0.001)]; 
inflow [phi_, FQin_] := (phi - β FQin) dx; density[qin_, qout_, qr_] := 
  (qin - qout + qr)/Vf;

dx = 1/6; capacity = 7500.; Kj = 150.; w = 100.; Vf = 100.; n = 60; m = 300; p = 24; 
RML = 18;α = 4300.; β = 0.1; L = 3.; delta = 1.; dt = 4./3600.; 

f = Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {a2, _Real} {a3, _Real}, {a4, _Real}, {a5,_Real}}, 
  Module[{k0 = ConstantArray[0, n], 
          kr = Table[Table[0, {i1, 1, p}], {i2, 1, n - 2}], 
          ϕ = 0,  
          Shutoff = False},
    j = 0;
    RMori = 
      Table[
        If[i1 dx < 2, 100 a1, 
          If[i1 dx < 4, 100 a2, 
            If[i1 dx < 6, 100 a3, 
              If[i1 dx < 8, 100 a4, 100 a5]]]], 
        {i1, 1,n - 2}];
    kr = ReplacePart[#, 1 -> (α delta/Vf)] & /@ kr; 
    NtwrkTT = TT = Plus @@ (Plus @@ kr);
    While[TT > 0, 
      TT = 0;
      qf = MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most@k0, Rest@k0}];
      ϕ = demand[1, #[[-1]] ] & /@ kr MapThread[gamma, {k0[[2 ;; -2]], k0[[3 ;;]]}];
      qin = inflow[ϕ, Most@qf];
      k0 += Join[{0}, density[Most@qf, Rest@qf, qin], {0}];
      RM = MapThread[Min[#1, #2] &, {RMori, flo[1, #[[RML]], #[[RML + 1]]] & /@ kr}];
      qr = 
        MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}, #3, {#4}] &, 
          {flo[1, ##] & @@@ Partition[#[[;; RML]], 2, 1] & /@ kr, 
           RM, 
           flo[1, ##] & @@@ Partition[#[[RML + 1 ;;]], 2, 1] & /@ kr, ϕ}];
      kr = 
        MapThread[(#1 + #2) &, 
          {Join[{0}, #] & /@ (density[Most@#,Rest@#, 0] & /@ qr), kr}];
      If[j > m && Shutoff == False, Shutoff = True; 
      kr = ReplacePart[#, 1 -> 0] & /@ kr];
      TT += Plus @@ k0; 
      TT += Plus @@ (Plus @@ kr); 
      NtwrkTT += TT; 
      j++;];
    NtwrkTT dt]]
```

When the function is evaluated at `f[39, 39, 39, 39, 39]`, it gives the following errors

> ```
> ReplacePart::argrx: ReplacePart called with 2 arguments; 3 arguments are expected. >>
> ReplacePart::argrx: ReplacePart called with 2 arguments; 3 arguments are expected. >>
> ReplacePart::argrx: ReplacePart called with 2 arguments; 3 arguments are expected. >>
> General::stop: Further output of ReplacePart::argrx will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> Compile::cpintlt: 3;;All at position 2 of k0[[3;;All]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> Compile::cpintlt: 3;;All at position 2 of k0[[3;;All]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> Compile::cset: Variable \[Phi] of type {_Integer,0} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,1}. >>
> Compile::cplist: density[Most[qf],Rest[qf],qin] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> Compile::cpapot: Compilation of (flo[1,##1]&)@@Compile`GetElement[System`Private`CompileSymbol[4],System`Private`CompileSymbol[5]] is not supported for the function argument flo[1,##1]&. The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> Compile::cpapot: Compilation of (flo[1,##1]&)@@Compile`GetElement[System`Private`CompileSymbol[4],System`Private`CompileSymbol[5]] is not supported for the function argument flo[1,##1]&. The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> Compile::cpapot: Compilation of (flo[1,##1]&)@@Compile`GetElement[System`Private`CompileSymbol[4],System`Private`CompileSymbol[5]] is not supported for the function argument flo[1,##1]&. The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> General::stop: Further output of Compile::cpapot will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> Compile::cpintlt: RML+1;;All at position 2 of Compile`GetElement[kr,System`Private`CompileSymbol[0]][[RML+1;;All]] should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> General::stop: Further output of Compile::cpintlt will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> Compile::cset: Variable kr of type {_Integer,2} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,0}. >>
> Compile::cset: Variable \[Phi] of type {_Integer,0} encountered in assignment of type {_Integer,1}. >>
> General::stop: Further output of Compile::cset will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
> Compile::cplist: density[Most[qf],Rest[qf],qin] should be a tensor of type Integer, Real, or Complex; evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>
> ```

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, but please see the edited question.

Comment: It contains `kr = ReplacePart[#, 1 -> (α delta/Vf)] & /@ kr;` So you quite clearly invoke `ReplacePart` with 2 args, and if it wants 3 then it's no surprise when it complains.

Comment: ReplacePart only needs 2 arguments and works fine when used in the Module, please see http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplacePart.html, but MMA wants 3 args when I recode it in a `Compile` function. This is confusing!!

Comment: The syntax of ReplacePart ([documentation for V5.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/ReplacePart)) has changed. It might be that `Compile` hasn't learned that change (a probable reason is that newer versions with the new syntax can use patterns which `Compile` couldn't support anyway). In an uncompiled evalation the old syntax still seems to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With

**1.** the note about the behavior of `ReplacePart` inside `Compile` made by [Daniel Lichtblau](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/51/daniel-lichtblau) and [Albert Retey](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/169/albert-retey) in the comments above,

**2.** the correction for the simple mistake `{a2, _Real} {a3, _Real}`,

**3.** the note about `All` inside `Compile` [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45544/1871),

**4.** a modification for the uncompiled definition of `qr` i.e. changing

```
qr =  MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}, #3, {#4}] &, 
   {flo[1, ##] & @@@ Partition[#[[;; RML]], 2, 1] & /@ kr, 
    RM, 
    flo[1, ##] & @@@ Partition[#[[RML + 1 ;;]], 2, 1] & /@ kr, ϕ}];
```

into

```
qr = MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}, #3, {#4}] &, 
   {MapThread[flo[1, #, #2] &, {#[[1 ;; RML - 1]], #[[2 ;; RML]]}] & /@ kr, 
    RM, 
    MapThread[flo[1, #, #2] &, {#[[RML + 1 ;; -2]], #[[RML + 2 ;; -1]]}] & /@ kr, ϕ}];
```

**5.** notes in [my answer for your latter question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46160/1871),

I fixed your code, now for `f[39, 39, 39, 39, 39]` it's about 40 times faster than the uncompiled one:

```
f = With[{dx = 1/6, capacity = 7500., Kj = 150., w = 100., Vf = 100., n = 60, m = 300, 
          p = 24, RML = 18, α = 4300., β = 0.1, L = 3., delta = 1., dt = 4./3600.}, 
   Module[{demand, supply, flo, gam, inflow, density}, 
    demand = Function[{n, k}, Min[k Vf, n capacity]]; 
    supply = Function[{n, k}, Min[(n Kj - k) w, n capacity]]; 
    flo = Function[{n, ku, kd}, Evaluate[Min[demand[n, ku], supply[n, kd]]]]; 
    gamma = Function[{ku, kd}, Evaluate[Min[1, supply[L, kd]/(demand[L, ku] + 0.001)]]]; 
    inflow = Function[{phi, FQin}, (phi - β FQin) dx]; 
    density = Function[{qin, qout, qr}, (qin - qout + qr)/Vf]; 
    Compile[{{a1, _Real}, {a2, _Real} , {a3, _Real}, {a4, _Real}, {a5, _Real}}, 
     Module[{k0 = Table[0., {n}], 
       kr = Table[0., {n - 2}, {p}], 
       ϕ = {0.}, Shutoff = False, 
       j = 0, RMori, NtwrkTT, TT, qf, qin, RM, qr},
      RMori = Table[If[i1 dx < 2, 100 a1, 
         If[i1 dx < 4, 100 a2, 
          If[i1 dx < 6, 100 a3, 
           If[i1 dx < 8, 100 a4, 100 a5]]]], {i1, 1, n - 2}];
      kr = (ReplacePart[#1, (α delta)/Vf, 1] &) /@ kr;
      NtwrkTT = TT = Plus @@ Plus @@ kr;
      While[TT > 0,
       TT = 0;
       qf = MapThread[flo[L, ##] &, {Most[k0], Rest[k0]}]; 
       ϕ = (demand[1, #1[[-1]]] &) /@ kr MapThread[gamma, {k0[[2 ;; -2]], k0[[3 ;; -1]]}]; 
       qin = inflow[ϕ, Most[qf]]; 
       k0 += Join[{0}, density[Most[qf], Rest[qf], qin], {0}];        
       RM = MapThread[Min[#1, #2]&, {RMori, (flo[1, #1[[RML]], #1[[RML + 1]]] &)/@kr}];
       qr = MapThread[Join[#1, {#2}, #3, {#4}] &, 
             {MapThread[flo[1, #, #2] &, {#[[1 ;; RML - 1]], #[[2 ;; RML]]}] & /@ kr, 
              RM, 
              MapThread[flo[1, #, #2] &, {#[[RML + 1 ;; -2]], #[[RML + 2 ;; -1]]}] &/@kr, 
              ϕ}];        
       kr = MapThread[(#1 + #2) &, 
         {Join[{0}, #] & /@ (density[Most@#, Rest@#, 0] & /@ qr), kr}];
       If[j > m && Shutoff == False, 
          Shutoff = True; kr = (ReplacePart[#1, 0, 1] &) /@ kr]; TT += Plus @@ k0; 
          TT += Plus @@ Plus @@ kr; NtwrkTT += TT; j++;]; NtwrkTT dt], 
     CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}]]];
```