# Need help with C Code Generator

Tags: compile, c-codegenerator

I'm trying to use the *Mathematica* C Code Generator package to generate code that is to be included in a web application by a developer. I don't know any C, and this seems to be the only way to integrate my model with the web-app. I am having a lot of difficulties getting off the ground.

A persistent error seems to be that my iteration indices are not recognised as integers. Here's an example:

```
Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]
funct = Compile[{{M, _Real, 2}, {l, _Integer}},
  Module[{matrix = M, lag = l },
   columns = Length[Transpose[matrix]];
    Flatten[ 
      Join[ {{{Table[1, {columns - lag + 1}]}}, 
      Table[matrix[[;; , lag - i + 1 ;; columns - i + 1]] , {i, 1, lag}]} ] , 2]
    ], {{i, _Integer}}
]
```

This produces the following error:

> `Compile::cpintlt`: "1;;All at position 2 of `matrix[[1;;All,lag-i+1;;columns+i+1]]` should be either a nonzero integer or a vector of nonzero integers; evaluation will use the uncompiled function."

Finally when I export the C code, I get errors like

> `CCodeGenerate::wmreq`: "The expression `Function[{M,l,iCompile$18},Block[{i=iCompile$18},{All,i}]]` requires *Mathematica* to be evaluated. The function will be generated but can be expected to fail with a nonzero error code when executed. "

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to generate C from Mathematica and then use that C code to deploy in some sort of web app? To digress have you thought have just using webMathematica so that the Mathematica code gets deployed directly?

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, unfortunately, the client's security protocols don't allow us to install 3rd party software on their server; only what we write for them ourselves. It's an embuggerance.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `Compile` doesn't handle `1;;All` in `Span`, so why not just use explicit total number of rows?

```
Compile[{{matrix, _Real, 2}, {lag, _Integer}},
    Module[{rows, columns},
        {rows, columns} = Dimensions[matrix];
        Join[
            {Table[1., {columns - lag + 1}]},
            Flatten[
                Table[
                    matrix[[1 ;; rows, lag - i + 1 ;; columns - i + 1]],
                    {i, 1, lag}],
                1]]]] //
   CCodeGenerate[ #, "fun", "generatedfunc.c"] &
```

Also please note you leave the `columns` as an external variable, which will cause the `MainEvaluate` call.

### Edit:

However, as pointed out by [xzczd](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/1871/xzczd), `Compile` does handle `All` correctly as `matrix[[All, lag - i + 1 ;; columns - i + 1]]`.

Comment: Thanks so much Silvia. Now I get a new error:

`CCodeGenerate::wmreq: The expression Compile GetElement requires Mathematica to be evaluated.   The function will be generated but can be expected to fail with a nonzero error code when executed.`

Comment: @zab I didn't get any error or warning :( Have you tried it in a fresh-started Mathematica?

Comment: Personally I really feel this limit of `Compile` unreasonable… BTW, another way to circumvent it is to just use `All` i.e. `matrix[[All, lag - i + 1 ;; columns - i + 1]]`.

Comment: Thanks so much Silvia. It is working now. Looks like my understanding of local and external variables is lacking. I'll read up. 

I am finding the documentation on Compile and CCodeGenerator less than comprehensive.

Comment: @xzczd You're right! I made a too hasty conclusion..

Comment: @zab I never used `CCodeGenerator` before, but there is an official application [MathCode C++](http://www.wolfram.com/products/applications/mathcode/), which I think is an advanced version of `CCodeGenerator`.

Comment: Thanks so much Silvia and everyone else who contributed. Code compiling properly now. 

One more question: The resulting C code wants tensors as inputs, but the input generated by other components of my process is in array form (SQL). How do I bridge this gap?

Comment: @zab I don't really know C, but I think the *tensor* word in MMA context is the *array* in C context, isn't it?

Comment: @Silvia, yes - that's what I thought too, but the C code contains a lot of "tensor" declarations. When I run it with some array input, it gives me errors.

Comment: @zab Maybe check the *WolframCompileLibrary.h* file will give you some clue? Also have you installed the header and library files correctly?